# Is there a special name for a linear transformation from a vector space to itself?

Tags: vector-spaces, terminology

This concept seems too important to not have a special name, yet I've never seen one.

Comment: They are called *linear endomorphisms*.

Comment: I normally would say that a _linear map_ is an _endomorphism_. If your vector space is $V$, an endomorphism is an element of $\mathrm{End}(V)$. For a _linear transformation_ I would use _automorphism_, i.e. an element of $\mathrm{GL}(V)$.

Comment: I've always known those as "linear **operators**"

Comment: *endos* (Greek) inner, *morphe* (Greek) form, *linea* (Latin) line. So, a linear endomorphism are functions from the space to inside it (to itself), preserving the form (the structure), the linear structure in this case.

Comment: Absolutely no one uses linear operators for linear transformations from the space to itself. A linear operator is just a linear transformation between two vector spaces, and its use is more predominant when the spaces are spaces of functions.

Comment: @Totoro, that's not true. While some use "linear operator" to mean "linear map," others use "linear operator" to mean more specifically a linear endomorphism. For example, Sheldon Axler's book "Linear Algebra Done Right" uses "linear operator" to mean "linear endomorphism."

Comment: @JonWarneke Improper use.

Comment: @user551819, Friedberg's Linear Algebra also uses 'linear operator' to refer to lienar endomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

I fairly remember reading somewhere that some mathematicians call linear maps from one vector space to itself, an operator.